# how to process one or more items in PayPal shopping cart

Tags: paypal, cart, multiple-instances

I would like some recommendations about open source or other solutions for processing one or more items collected using PayPal's shopping cart button. Thanks.

At this point, I am researching, looking for possible solutions.

Logically, PayPal's "add to cart" and "view cart" buttons suggests I will be sending an array and they will be returning verifications for that array. If that is true, I can use Javascript to generate a page with the appropriate images and links to access the purchased items. I will focus on PayPal's articles about the shopping cart data.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any ecommerce shopping cart ever made is compatible with PayPal Checkout, so you can essentially use anything that suits your other needs.

Start with searching the web or [PayPal's Partner Directory](https://www.paypal.com/business/platforms-and-marketplaces/directory)